# Is it possible to create a contact form without using a plugin?

Tags: contact

I am going over a tutorial for WP and in it, the instructor is able to add in a contact form field from a menu option "Add Contact Form", I do not see this on 4.2.2.

Is this possible to do without using a contact form plugin for this?

**Edit:** After scouring the web, I came across this link that goes over similar steps:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/contact-form/

In it, they mention the following:

How to add a Contact Form

1. Hover over My Sites and click on WP Admin
2. Click Pages > Add New
3. Click Add Contact Form
4. Click Insert Into Post to generate your form’s shortcode
5. Publish the page, and view your form

I do not have the option for 'Add Contact Form' next to 'Add Media' above the text box of the page. Is there an option to turn this on somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Jetpack which is a product of Automattic/WordPress you will then have the form feature you mention in the link you provided.

http://jetpack.me/support/contact-form/

Comment: Bummer can't get this to work as my WP project is local and not on the Wordpress.com site, as it tries to connect using this plug-in. `Your website needs to be publicly accessible to use Jetpack: site_inaccessible
Error Details: The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site http://wordpress.local [IXR -32300: transport error: http_request_failed Couldn't resolve host 'wordpress.local']`

Comment: Once you make it live then it would be easy to add, you will need to register for a wordpress.com account too.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't Core. The tutorial is using a plugin, or something built into the theme.

You don't need to use a plugin, but if you don't you will need to code your own form and form handler.